# Hide edge labels in vis.js-network

Tags: javascript, label, vis.js-network

I would like to simply show/hide the labels of the *edges* of my vis.js-network - is this possible?

I have [tried](https://jsfiddle.net/w91t5xm4/1/) to update the edges in the vis.js-data structure:

- Delete the `label` property - doesn't work
- Set the `label` to `undefined` - doesn't work
- Set the `label` to `''` - doesn't work
- Set the `label` to `' '` - works

I would prefer a network-wise toggle of some kind, but I haven't found one.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to updating the `label` property on each edge is to change the font color to be [transparent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword) for all edges. The `setOptions()` method can be used to update the options and will apply all edges in the network. The options `edges.font.color` and `edges.font.strokeColor` should both be updated, then returned to their original values to display the edges.

Example below and also at https://jsfiddle.net/rk9s87ud/.

```js
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
]);

var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 2, label: 'Edge 1' },
  { from: 2, to: 3, label: 'Edge 2' },
  { from: 3, to: 4, label: 'Edge 3' },
  { from: 4, to: 5, label: 'Edge 4' },
]);

var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};

var options = {
  nodes: {
    // Set any other options, for example node color to gold
    color: 'gold'
  },
  edges: {
    font: { 
      // Set to the default colors as per the documentation
      color: '#343434',
      strokeColor: '#ffffff'
    }
  }
}

var hiddenEdgeTextOptions = {
  edges: {
    font: {
      // Set the colors to transparent
      color: 'transparent',
      strokeColor: 'transparent'
    }
  }
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

var displayLabels = true;
document.getElementById('toggleLabels').onclick = function() {
  if(displayLabels){
    // Apply options for hidden edge text
    // This will override the existing options for text color
    // This does not clear other options (e.g. node.color)
    network.setOptions(hiddenEdgeTextOptions);
    displayLabels = false;
  } else {
    // Apply standard options
    network.setOptions(options);
    displayLabels = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleLabels">Toggle labels</button>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Comment: This really does hide the labels. My reasons for hiding the labels though are due to performance. I see a significant reduction in performance when zooming in and out when having a *large* network. Making the labels transparent doesn't seem to help with my performance issues, but it makes sense, since the labels probably still are rendered even though they are completely transparent.